# How I can proceed when user accepts to leave page once window.beforeunload event is triggered?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

During a procedure that takes a bit of time, I use the `beforeunload` event to ask user if they want to leave or not:

```js
window.beforeunload = function(e) {
  var confirmAction = confirm("Wanna leave? This will BREAK the page.");
  if (confirmAction) {
    //leavePage
  }
};
```

```html
<a href="en.wikipedia.org">Leave page</a>
```

If `confirmAction` is true, how I can allow the user to leave this page?

Comment: What do I need to do to make your function actually run ?

Comment: You using even incorrectly, you should return text that will be displayed, not display it yourself https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload